# getId from selected EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener, selecteditem

this is my first question, I've made a code to add views from a SQLite database and I'd like to select an EditText I've added and when I change this value do an action. I don't know the Id of this EditText so I can't use findByValue on this case. How can I get this? Here is my code:

```
LinearLayout pantalla;
int[] edits;
int adicionales = 0;
int IdSelected; //I want to put the Id here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_platos);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    edits = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.editTexts); //these are the Id values that I've created on String file
    pantalla = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pantallaPlatos);

    CargarPlatos(); //this calls to create all the EditTexts

}

public void CargarPlatos() {
    pantalla.removeAllViews();

    List<tablaPlatos> Platos = Consumo.db.getAllPlatos();
    int i = 0;
    for (tablaPlatos platos : Platos) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        pantalla.addView(linearLayout);

        EditText item = new EditText(this);
        String log = platos.getName();
        item.setText(log);
        item.setId(edits[i]);
        ;
        i++;
        linearLayout.addView(item);

        EditText item2 = new EditText(this);
        String log2 = platos.getValue();
        item2.setText(log2);
        item2.setId(edits[i]);
        item2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        i++;
        linearLayout.addView(item2);
    }

}

// When I click on an EditText I want to know his Id
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    IdSelected=v.getId();
    //And then do something
}
```

[ScreenCapture of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biMHZ.jpg)

Really hope you can help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: You really should make `pantallaPlatos` a ListView

Comment: And, not sure why you want an OnClick action. You should use a TextWatcher to know when the text of the EditText has changed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually my pantallaPlatos is a Layout where all the EditText are added, I want to modify one of those EditText but with OnClick I need to declare first the Id and I am charging them after.

Comment: I've added a ScreenCapture of the application, for example, I want to select the EditText where it says 55.9 and change it to 60, when I do that I want the EditText below changes to 60/2. All those EditText are on a SQLite database so it can be more and more EditTexts and I don't want to declare one by one to use a TextWatcher. How can I do?

Comment: I dont see any setOnclickListener() ???

Comment: if I use a setOnClickListener I need something like:
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
edt.setOnClickListener;

Right? well, i can't use that because my Id must be for the EditText I select

Comment: No, you don't need any ID. You have `EditText edt = new EditText(this);` then you can simply do `edt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thanks for trying to help me, I found my solution with OnGlobalFocusChangeListener

I added this code on the OnCreate:

```
    pantalla.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalFocusChanged(View oldFocus, View newFocus) {
            if (oldFocus!=null){
                Toast.makeText(Platos.this, "Id: " + String.valueOf(oldFocus.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (newFocus!=null){
                Toast.makeText(Platos.this, "Id: " + String.valueOf(newFocus.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

with this I can see the Id of the focused EditText